# How do I prevent OS X 10.8 from autoconnecting to a specific wireless network?

Tags: macos, mac, network, wifi

I have two wireless networks at home. I want my Mac to autoconnect to one of them, but not the other. However, I do not want to remove the other network from my preferred list, since I want to keep the SSID/password saved for when I do need to connect to it. I've listed the network that I want to connect to at the very top of my preferred list, but my Mac still chooses to connect to the other network about 50% of the time. Is there any way to prevent it from connecting to that network while still keeping that network's credentials saved?

Answer (score 3):

From another answer: [How to disable automatic wifi connection?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/39922/how-to-disable-automatic-wifi-connection)

> The only way to stop from automatically joining a preferred or known wifi network, is to not store the password for that network and type it in each time without clicking the "save password" button.

If you have a network remembered, and the credentials stored, there does not appear to be a way to prevent the system from trying to connect to it on sight.

Another answer with a somewhat related conclusion that may shed more light on the way the wifi autoconnect works: [Prevent my Mac from connecting to an unsecure Wi-Fi network?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/90036/prevent-my-mac-from-connecting-to-an-unsecure-wi-fi-network?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Consider removing the network from your preferred network list (although I know you would like to avoid this) and create a new Keychain item in the Keychain Access App. Use the SSID as the Account Name. This will save and secure your password in the same way that all of your saved passwords are saved. It may add an extra step to joining this secondary network (i.e. retrieving your your credentials from Keychain Access) - but your password is saved and secure.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Open Network Preferences
2. Click Advanced
3. Select your preferred network for autoconnection from the Preferred Network List and drag it above the network you do not want your pc to automatically connect to.