# How can I disconnect from all WiFi networks, yet leave WiFi antenna on so Internet Sharing will work properly?

Tags: macbook-pro, sharing, internet

I would like to have my MacBook's Wi-Fi antenna on, but *not* be connected to any wireless network. Instead I would like for my MacBook to share its Thunderbolt-to-Ethernet connection so my iPhone can get a taste. *(My office was built on an ancient Bermudian triangle sanctuary.)*

I am using the same settings, toggling things hasn't worked yet:

- [x] Internet Sharing
- Share from: [_Thunderbolt_Ethernet___]
- To computers using: [x] Wi-Fi

(green light) Internet Sharing: On

However the Wi-Fi icon in the notifications area usually shows a vertical arrow when it is working properly. Right now it just connects to the nearby networks (public and login walled) and refuses to broadcast, even though the green light still says 'On'.

Anyway I suspect that my computer's trying to connect to Wi-Fi networks, it indefinitely forgoes its opportunity to broadcast its own SSID. How can I make this work again?

Comment: Do you still want to use those WiFis or newer ?

Comment: If you want to use them on command see this answer http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/39925/46541

Answer (score 1):

Change your network profile so that the preferred order has your thunderbolt connection at the top. This will make OSX use it over wifi even if a known wifi access point is available.

With a working internet connection just configure internet sharing and it should just work.

I know from experience that this works, I have done it many times on snow leopard, should work the same way on later releases of osx.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the keychain and remove the passwords from your preferred networks.

Now they will not auto connect.

If it is a public without password delete it.

Comment: I don't doubt that that is the only way to do this, and it infuriates me a little more alongside those where "You can't" is actually the correct answer.

Comment: If i read your requirements, then that is the only way that I know. "Leave the WiFi on but disable the Auto connect to pref WiFi". You can also delete the Pref WiFi from your profiles all together and disable the remember the ....but I assumed you do want to connect to them eventually.

Comment: There is also a Terminal command to disassociate from any network "Airport -z"

Answer (score -1):

I found that the easy way to circumvent the auto-connection to other networks is to choose the Create Network... option that appears at the bottom of the WiFi drop-down.

Who knew.

[image: Create Network...]